# Dropdownlist dependiente de otro? ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Esta sección crea ofertas laborales (es un portal de empleo), del cual, se necesita elegir Area y Subarea. Al momento de seleccionar un Area, me deben aparecer las Subareas de esa Area. Dejo imagen para ver la composición de las tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi modelo de oferta laboral es este:

```
namespace ProyectoBase4.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class OfertaLaboral
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public OfertaLaboral()
    {
        this.OfertaPostulante = new HashSet<OfertaPostulante>();
    }

    public int Of_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> OfEmp_ID { get; set; }

    public string Of_Titulo { get; set; }
    public string Of_Puesto { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Of_Area { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Of_Subarea { get; set; }
    public string Of_Descrp { get; set; }
    public string Of_Lugar { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Of_Vacante { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Of_FechaIn { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Of_FechaFin { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Of_Salario { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Of_Jornada { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Of_Mov { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Of_Edu { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Of_TContrato { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Of_Estado { get; set; }

    public virtual Area Area { get; set; }
    public virtual Educacion Educacion { get; set; }
    public virtual Estado Estado { get; set; }
    public virtual Jornada_Compl Jornada_Compl { get; set; }
    public virtual Movilidad Movilidad { get; set; }
    public virtual Subarea Subarea { get; set; }
    public virtual TipoContrato TipoContrato { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<OfertaPostulante> OfertaPostulante { get; set; }
}
}
```

Como puedo hacer que mediante la elección de un campo en Area, me despliegue las Subareas correspondiente? Dejaré vista:

```
 <div class="">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Of_Titulo, htmlAttributes: new { style = "" })
                            <div class="">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Of_Titulo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Of_Titulo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Of_Area, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "", style = "margin-left:10px;" })
                            <div class="">
                                @Html.DropDownList("Of_Area", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control form-control-75", style = "margin-left:10px;" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Of_Area, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <br /><br /><br /><br />
                    <div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Of_Vacante, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "" })
                            <div class="">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Of_Vacante, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control form-control-50" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Of_Vacante, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Of_Salario, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "" })
                            <div class="">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Of_Salario, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control form-control-50" } })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Of_Subarea, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "", style = "margin-left:40px;" })
                            <div class="">
                                @Html.DropDownList("Of_Subarea", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control  form-control-75", style = "margin-left:40px;" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Of_Subarea, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Como mencioné antes, necesito que al elegir una opcion, despues al seleccionar la subopcion, me aparezcan sólo las opciones de esa area. Dejo imagen de ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano, muchas gracias!

Comment: Vas a tener que realizar lo siguiente: un evento onchange del dropdown principal, va a lanzar un POST mediante AJAX (para evitar el refresh) con el ID del valor que tiene, de tal manera que al ser procesado, puedas obtener una vista parcial que tenga el modelo de ese segundo dropdown o un JSON y te encargas de armar el contenido del `<select>` con todas las opciones que traes de vuelta.

Comment: Otra cosa que también puedes hacer, es usar los data-atributes, al tener ambas listas completas, sólo filtras en javascript los elementos del segundo dropdown basado en el ID del primer dropdown.

Comment: tienes algun ejemplo? soy muy nuevo en programación :(, gracias por responder!

Comment: Por el momento no. Revisa este workshop que hice hace un tiempo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY te dará un panorama para empezar. De nada :D

Comment: gracias, lo veré! :)